# Need SP to Reference multiple internal and external data points and provide a percentage

Tags: sharepoint-designer

My leadership wants to use SP to track our employee holiday leave requests by functional area to ensure we do not fall below minimum staffing levels.

So we there would be 8 days we are concerned with and there are roughly 7 functional groups.

As an example, we have 100 rating employees and can’t fall below 50% the day after Christmas. If everyone is listed in the SP and we update an employee to show as wanting leave for that day, will it drop us below 50 percent?

Can SP display this data in real time as we make adjustments, for the many different functional groups for each of the days we are concerned with? If so, how can this be done?